# zend based where clause disappearing

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework

I have a weird problem using socialEngine DB class (based on zend framework).
I wrote something like this:

```
$statusTable = Engine_Api::_()->getDbtable('actions', 'activity');
$myPosts = $statusTable->fetchAll($statusTable->select()
    ->where('subject_id = ?',$id)
    ->where('comment_count > ?',0)
    ->where('type = ?',$type)
    ->where('date > ?',$newer_than)
    ->order('date DESC')
    ->limit(intval($num_items)));
```

Its a part of a plugin a made, the problem is the query generated is somthing like this:

```
SELECT `engine4_activity_actions`.*
FROM `engine4_activity_actions`
WHERE (subject_id = 5) AND (comment_count > 0) AND (type = ) AND (date > )
ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 10
```

You can see that the $type and the $newer_than have disappeared, even though they have values ($type='status', $newer_than='01/01/2000')

EDIT:
It seems to respond only to integers and not strings, if i replace the 'status' with 0 it shows up in the query.

The server runs on php 5.3.2

Comment: That's odd. What happens if you hard code a value for $type and $newer_than (->where('type = ?','status')) just as a debugging step. Also try printing out $type and $newer_than right before you run this query to verify that they do have values.

Comment: It does the same thing, I noticed it happens only with strings, if i replace $type with 0 for example the value gets in the query. could it be that strings are not allowed or i should escape it somehow?

Comment: cast `$type` as string . it may not work but give it a try `->where('type = ?', (string )$type) ;`

Comment: nope, casting doesn't work...it's like it doesn't accept strings only integers

Comment: Is it possible date and type are integer in the table schema? Not sure if it would change something but its something to look into.

Comment: It actually makes sense, but the data types are varchar and datetime, so at least the varchar needs to respond to strings...

Comment: You say the query looks somethinng like this, Have tried echoibng the actual query? Just take it out of the fetchAll and echo it. Maybe something in there.

Answer (score 0):

There's a third optionnal argument on the where() method which is the type of your argument. Depending on your DB adapter it can maybe get an important thing to tell for the Zend_Db_Select query builder.
So you could try

```
->where('subject_id=?',$subject,'TEXT')
```

ZF API indicates as well "Note that it is more correct to use named bindings in your queries for values other than strings", this can help the query builder, to get the real type of your args, so you could try as well this way:

```
$myPosts = $statusTable->fetchAll($statusTable->select()
->where('subject_id=:psubject')
(...)
,array('psubject'=>$subject));
```